# Android 8.1 : 4G option not visible under Preferred Network type List in Network Settings UI

Tags: android, radiobuttonlist, cellular-network, android-8.1-oreo, 4g

My desired options

[image]

I'm building AOSP x86 image from source, i see that after flashing the built oreo image to the target system, **4G (recommended)** option shown in above image is not visible in the **Preferred network type** drop down list.

I have set `ro.telephony.default_network=9` in device.mk as given below. This `ro.telephony.default_network=9` is also reflected under build.prop of the target system.

> PRODUCT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES := 
> ro.ril.hsxpa=1 
> ro.ril.gprsclass=10 
> keyguard.no_require_sim=true 
> ro.com.android.dataroaming=true 
> media.sf.hwaccel=1 
> media.sf.omx-plugin=libffmpeg_omx.so 
> media.sf.extractor-plugin=libffmpeg_extractor.so 
> rild.libpath=/vendor/lib64/librapid-ril-core.so 
> ro.telephony.default_network=9

I can see **4G (recommended)** selected by default in Preferred network type, but if i click on Preferred network type menu and go inside i see only **3G** and **2G** Radio buttons.
4G (recommended) is missing in the drop down menu.

Once i select one of the **3G** or **2G** Radio button, there is no way i can switch back to **4G (recommended)** which was selected by default by the OS.

NOTE:  i'm successfully able to get 4G download speeds when 4G( recommended) selected by default in Preferred network type. Changing to 3G and 2G will successfully get respective speeds and able to see corresponding network type indicator icon in status bar. So functionally Internet data connectivity is working fine in all 3 modes (4G, 3G and 2G).

How to modify source files to make the 4G (recommended) radio button visible under Preferred network type as indicated in above attached image?

I'm not able to enter engineering mode by dialing `*#*#4636#*#*` (any answers to enable this also grateful)

Answer (score 0):

Reference: http://paldan.altervista.org/lte-in-aosp-preferred-network-settings/

To enable **4g(recommended)** radio under **Preferred Network Type** menu, you must set **config_enabled_lte** to *true* in packages/services/Telephony/res/values/config.xml

```
<bool name="config_enabled_lte" translatable="false">true</bool>
```